# cakephp: I want a simple select box with options and no optgroup

Tags: cakephp, select

The select box for forum_categories in the cupcake forum plugin doesn't allow me to select its options. When I rollover the options with my mouse, the highlight stays at 'Select a Forum'. The following is the original

```
<?php
echo $form->input('forum_category_id', array(
    'options' => $forums,
    'empty' => '-- '. __d('forum', 'Select a Forum', true) .' --',
    'label' => __d('forum', 'Forum Category', true)
));
?>
```

And i modified it to:

```
<?php
echo $form->input('Topic.forum_category_id',array(
    'empty' => 'Select a Forum',
    'options' => $forums
));
?>
```

The following is the html code it is generating:

```
<select name="data[Topic][forum_category_id]" id="TopicForumCategoryId">
<option value="">Select a Forum</option>
<optgroup label="Summer Camp">
</optgroup>
</select>
```

The find stmt in the forumcategory model:

```
$forums = $this->Forum->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Forum.status' => 0,
            'Forum.accessView <=' => $access,
            'Forum.access_level_id' => $accessLevels
        ),
        'order' => 'Forum.orderNo ASC'
    ));
```

How can I get rid of the optgroup in the html code above? I just want a simple select box with options and no optgroup like the following:

```
<select name="data[Topic][forum_category_id]" id="TopicForumCategoryId">
<option value="">Select a Forum</option>
<option value="1">Summer Camp</option>
</select>
```

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't allow me select its options."?  Please post the HTML code it's generating.

Comment: Sudhir, no $forums is not an array, it is listing fine inside the select box. eg of $forums is 'summer camp'.

Comment: Dave i have edited my code to include the HTML code it is generating. It doesn't allow me to highlight and click on its options. 'Select a Forum' remains highlighted even when i move the mouse down.

Comment: Ok, it is not allowing me to select coz' 'Summer Camp' is an optgroup. I need to have several options below the optgroup for selection. Thanks dave for the guidance. I will try to go and fix it now.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work finally. The problem was in understanding the forum_category model's function that builds $forums and adding some data in the database to get subforums to display in the select box. It was some code that looked complicated that I had to spend time understanding.

Answer (score 1):

probably a bit late but
you get opt groups when
your options looks like this :

```
$arr = array(
    'optgroup' => array(
        '1','2','3'),
     'optgroup2' => array(
         '1',2,3)
);                              
echo $this->Form->input('some',array('options' => $arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Topic.forum_category_id', array('options' => $forums, 'empty' => 'Select a Forum'));
```

Comment: i tried ur suggestion and it still doesn't work. I'm not able to select its options.